# What should I do with a low quality question with an acceptable and upvoted answer

Tags: discussion

While reviewing low quality post queue, I found a question posted by a true beginner that could not help any one else. I did not note it first, and now I can no longer find it, maybe someone else deleted it.

The OP create an object in ruby, tried to set required attributes but forgot to qualify them, so he only created local variables and did not understand the error at saving time. He got a quite acceptable answer voted at +5 that explained the bases of accessing fields in ruby.

IMHO the question truely should be deleted, but the answer should not. As I have little experience in SO, I skipped the question letting others take the decision. But now I wonder : what should I have done ?

Comment: The question you're describing doesn't sound that bad to me. It sounds like they had a fairly clear problem (error message) and a code sample that demonstrated the problem. Those two things would make it better than about half of the new questions I see. It might be reasonable to downvote it for a lack of research, but it doesn't sound like the kind of question that should be deleted.

Comment: Remember the set of people who might be helped by a question and answer includes beginners.

Comment: As often, this sort of discussion, triggered by noticing something from a particular question and trying to generalise, is better accompanied with a link to the actual question.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan The problem with questions like these is not that nobody else would ever have the problem, but rather the issues aren't discoverable.  There's often no good way for people having those problems to find that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments of  murgatroid99 and Patricia Shanahan, I conclude that a not so good quality question that is not one of the explicit deletion reasons (spam, off topic, duplicate ...) should not be deleted, mainly if one of its answers is good because the answer may help others.